# What is faster in C#, an if statement, or a virtual function call to a function that does nothing? And why?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, virtual-functions

Say you have a class called `MyClass` which has a certain behavior encapsulated using a reference (`myBehavior`) to another class called `Behavior`.  By default `MyClass` should have no behavior.

For instances which hadn't set `myBehavior` to anything after it was initialized   -  Would it be more speed efficient if `myBehavior` was initialized to `null`, and each time it was needed checked with `if(myBehavior)` or would it be faster if it were initialized to an instance of a `NullBehavior`, derived from `Behavior`, which does nothing?  and why?

```
class MyClass
{
   Behavior myBehavior = null;

   void doSomething()
   {
      if(myBehavior)
      {
         myBehavior.performAction();
      }
   }
}
```

or:

```
class NullBehavior : Behavior
{
   override void performAction()
   {
      // don't do anything
   }
}

class MyClass
{
   Behavior myBehavior = new NullBehavior(); // or equals some static universal instance of NullBehavior

   void doSomething()
   {
      myBehavior.performAction();
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it would be more efficient (and even if it was, the difference would be very very small) - But it is certainly not a good programming practice

Comment: @RafaelCardoso - which is not good programming practice?

Comment: Imagine you have a solution with 2 thousand classes. Would you duplicate all of them? What about testing? Everytime you added a method in one class you would have to add in the other as well and so forth..

Comment: You have to measure yourself but before you do you probably want to read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant),

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Why would I duplicate any of them?Say there are 200 variations of performAction() needed,but in the future I want to be able to extend this and create new behaviors at any time,like a Strategy Pattern or a Template method, but only for this particular operation.The amount of variations of Behavior wouldn't require any other classes to be duplicated, and MyClass wouldn't ever need to me inherited or modified.On a side note, I'm not arguing since there's clearly a consensus, but for future reference, how is this too broad?Serhiyb was able to fully answer my question quite briefly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's imagine what will happen with `ASM` code (after `IL`):

- wrapping it with `if` will generate extra `mov` + `cmp` + `jnz` instructions.
- calling function will execute `call` and `ret` calls which affect callstack maintenance (saving and restoring). It will probably generate something like: `call ...` then `push ebp`  `mov  ebp, esp` `... pop ebp` `ret`to save it and then extra code to restore it.

Obviously calling function consume more CPU operations comparing to `if`. But on other hand if your call function will be called each time (i.e. `myBehavior` is typically set) then we are wasting extra operation on `jnz`/`if`.

So if you can predict that `myBehaviour` will be most likely set (not null / NullBehavior) then you should go with second option without extra `if` but if it's more likely to be `null` then it worth wrapping it with `if`.